# 2 ways to write to .txt file 1 not working

Tags: python-3.x

I'm probably doing something wrong here, i have been learning the Python syntax and it seems fairly easy and non strict, in these 2 examples:

This works:

```
with open("data2.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.write(api_all_data_instantly.text)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
f3 = open("data3.txt", "w")
f3.write(api_all_data_instantly.text)
```

It's not a permissions error or anything like that, data3.txt is not being written to, as far as i can see the code does the same thing or am i wrong? just so i can learn for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the file at the end:

```
# your code
f3 = open("data3.txt", "w")
f3.write(api_all_data_instantly.text)

#add this
f3.close()
```

Comment: i JUST did that and came here to post :) that was the issue, in other languages you don't need to (but obviously you should) close the handle after writing, i would have thought it would still have written to the file, but at least i know now :) thanks again.

Comment: you should use `context manager`, which is with the `with`. There it does for you (closing the file at the end = when existing the scope).. Make sure you don't write an empty text to the file, because you write with `"w"`

Comment: Thank you Aaron, so the close was included with the first code example and that is why it worked, becaase i never closed that either, thank you again :)